# Missing transactions from Authorize.Net transaction api

Tags: authorize.net

I'm pulling transactions from Authorize.Net through the transaction reporting API for a customer (I don't have access to their dashboard). Yesterday, I was able to pull about 85 transactions through the `GetUnsettledTransactionList`  call. Today neither the `GetTransactionList`, or the `GetUnsettledTransactionList` calls will pull the those transactions. They pull other transactions, but not the ones that were in an unsettled state as of yesterday.

I'm guessing they've been settled, but not able to be pulled from the API, yet. Is there a state in which the transactions will reside where they cannot be pulled by either endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly the case. There appears to be a window of time once a transaction is settled where it cannot be retrieved by the transaction reporting API.